# Black screen with dual monitors (10.9.3)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

I have been experiencing a problem with my Macbook Pro (latest version) when connecting it to a dual monitor.

I usually click on the trackpad to wake the computer immediately after it has gone into sleep mode but ever since I have started using dual monitors the computer doesn't wake instantly.

I will see the outline of my mouse but the background remains black.

Here is what the console shows after the sleep-wake up
[image]

What have I tried:

To get around this problem I have just changed the sleep time on my computer but that is only a temporary solution.

I also contacted Apple support who suggested a PRAM reset but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Interestingly my roommate has the same problem with his Mac (both are on 10.9.3) so I am wondering if this might be an issue with Apple's dual monitor support and not a hardware issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you look in the console you will find out it is still busy putting the computer to sleep, so waking it up immediately is a problem. it is probably resolving the dual monitor set up. If you want to know more, publish the console report here.

Comment: This might be a bad question but where is the console, and how do I access it?

Comment: sorry for me just assuming. The Console is a application in your utility folder. It collects information on what you computer is doing. It is used for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You can see what I can see! now disable the log in and try again

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you disable automatic login and reboot with the monitor/s connected, does the issue occur at the login screen?  This sounds similar to two issues I'm currently working with, both Macs are connected to external displays and both are updated to 10.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

10.9.4 purports to fix sleep-wake issues.  I know on my rMBP (pre-Haswell) I'd have a similar issue after disconnecting from a Thunderbolt display, and it's been resolved since upgrading.